# SOAP: RequestRecipientToken - "Invalid Recipient" despite matching from RequestStatus

Tags: docusignapi

I'm testing embedded signing and I've ran into the following error:

"The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified envelope"

This worked for one envelope, but now does not for the second. Even though they have the exact same information.

Below is the response from **RequestStatus**:

```
     <RequestStatusResponse xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
         <RequestStatusResult>
            <RecipientStatuses>
              <RecipientStatus>
                  <Type>Signer</Type>
                  <Email>PLAT-2445@OUTLOOK.COM</Email>
                  <UserName>RANDOM GUY</UserName>
                  <RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
                  <Sent>2014-07-07T08:18:19.98</Sent>
                  <DeclineReason xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <Status>Sent</Status>
                  <RecipientIPAddress/>
                  <ClientUserId>PLAT-2445</ClientUserId>
                  <CustomFields/>
               </RecipientStatus>
            </RecipientStatuses>
            <EnvelopeID>0f2c122f-cb03-46cb-93cc-f0867c7c46df</EnvelopeID>
         </RequestStatusResult>
      </RequestStatusResponse>
```

**RequestRecipientToken**

```
    <ns1:RequestRecipientToken>
        <ns1:EnvelopeID>0f2c122f-cb03-46cb-93cc-f0867c7c46df</ns1:EnvelopeID>
        <ns1:ClientUserID>PLAT-2445</ns1:ClientUserID>
        <ns1:Username>RANDOM GUY</ns1:Username>
        <ns1:Email>PLAT-2445@OUTLOOK.COM</ns1:Email>
        <ns1:AuthenticationAssertion>
            <ns1:AssertionID>22b97ae7-c663-4135-8e5d-3c73e7461ffe</ns1:AssertionID>
            <ns1:AuthenticationInstant>2014-07-02T10:26:03.245-04:00</ns1:AuthenticationInstant>
            <ns1:AuthenticationMethod>Password</ns1:AuthenticationMethod>
            <ns1:SecurityDomain>Security.com</ns1:SecurityDomain>
        </ns1:AuthenticationAssertion>
        <ns1:ClientURLs></ns1:ClientURLs>
    </ns1:RequestRecipientToken>
```

**Response RequestRecipientToken**

```
  <soap:Fault>
     <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
     <faultstring>The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified envelope.</faultstring>
     <faultactor>https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx</faultactor>
     <detail>
        <ErrorCode xmlns="missing in Web.Config">123</ErrorCode>
        <ErrorReason xmlns="missing in Web.Config">The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified envelope.</ErrorReason>
     </detail>
  </soap:Fault>
```

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out.

**ROOT CAUSE:**

I created two envelopes with the same recipient info. The RecipientToken worked for the first envelope, but during signing of the first envelope, I adopted my signature with a different spelling of my name.

For the envelope that failed, I updated the UserName from RequestRecipientToken to match my signature I just adopted. Now it is successful.

**RESOLUTION:**

I've chosen to use a unique ClientUserId for each captive recipient during envelope creation.